# How to prevent rows adjustment after they are expanded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am working with [antd table](https://ant.design/components/table/) and [antd transfer](https://ant.design/components/transfer/) component and I am facing a small challenge with CSS.

I have created a [small example with codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-mendeleev-hhcw5). If I try to expand a row, you will see that other columns try to adjust themselves. Is there a way I could prevent this? I do not want the rows to adjust themselves. The table should feel the same after the expansion as it was before the expansion.

This is code from the sandbox link I shared above that generates the table.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Transfer, Table, Tag } from "antd";

function difference(listOne, listTwo) {
  const set1 = new Set(listOne);
  const set2 = new Set(listTwo);
  const difference = new Set([...set1].filter(x => !set2.has(x)));
  return Array.from(difference);
}
// Customize Table Transfer
const TableTransfer = ({ leftColumns, rightColumns, ...restProps }) => (
  <Transfer {...restProps}>
    {({
      direction,
      filteredItems,
      onItemSelectAll,
      onItemSelect,
      selectedKeys: listSelectedKeys,
      disabled: listDisabled
    }) => {
      const columns = direction === "left" ? leftColumns : rightColumns;

      const rowSelection = {
        getCheckboxProps: item => ({ disabled: listDisabled || item.disabled }),
        onSelectAll(selected, selectedRows) {
          const treeSelectedKeys = selectedRows
            .filter(item => !item.disabled)
            .map(({ key }) => key);
          const diffKeys = selected
            ? difference(treeSelectedKeys, listSelectedKeys)
            : difference(listSelectedKeys, treeSelectedKeys);
          onItemSelectAll(diffKeys, selected);
        },
        onSelect({ key }, selected) {
          onItemSelect(key, selected);
        },
        selectedRowKeys: listSelectedKeys
      };

      return (
        <Table
          rowSelection={rowSelection}
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={filteredItems}
          size="small"
        />
      );
    }}
  </Transfer>
);

const mockTags = ["eg", "gg", "e"];

const mockData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  let data = {
    key: i.toString(),
    title: `eq${i + 1}`,
    description: `description of eq${i + 1}`,
    disabled: false, //i % 4 === 0,
    tag: mockTags[i % 3]
  };

  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    const children = [
      {
        key: i.toString() + "children",
        title: `children-${i + 1}`,
        description: `children description-${i + 1}`,
        disabled: true,
        tag: "tag"
      }
    ];
    data["children"] = children;
  }
  mockData.push(data);
}

const originTargetKeys = mockData
  .filter(item => +item.key % 3 > 1)
  .map(item => item.key);

const leftTableColumns = [
  {
    dataIndex: "title",
    title: "Name"
  },
  {
    dataIndex: "tag",
    title: "Tag",
    render: tag => <Tag>{tag}</Tag>
  },
  {
    dataIndex: "description",
    title: "Description"
  }
];
const rightTableColumns = [
  {
    dataIndex: "title",
    title: "Names"
  },
  {
    dataIndex: "tag",
    title: "Tag",
    render: tag => <Tag>{tag}</Tag>
  },
  {
    dataIndex: "description",
    title: "Description"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    targetKeys: originTargetKeys
  };

  onChange = nextTargetKeys => {
    this.setState({ targetKeys: nextTargetKeys });
  };

  render() {
    const { targetKeys, disabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <TableTransfer
          className="table-transfer"
          dataSource={mockData}
          titles={[
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" checked />
              Equipment <input type="checkbox" checked /> Groups
            </div>,
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" checked />
              Equipment <input type="checkbox" checked /> Groups
            </div>
          ]}
          targetKeys={targetKeys}
          disabled={disabled}
          showSearch={true}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          filterOption={(inputValue, item) =>
            item.title.indexOf(inputValue) !== -1 ||
            item.tag.indexOf(inputValue) !== -1
          }
          leftColumns={leftTableColumns}
          rightColumns={rightTableColumns}
          locale={{
            itemUnit: "Equipment",
            itemsUnit: "Equipments",
            notFoundContent: "The list is empty",
            searchPlaceholder: "Search here"
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to constraint your columns `width`, [for example](https://s2kg7.codesandbox.io/), try this on the `leftTableColumns` and notice the difference with the right one:

```js
const leftTableColumns = [
  {
    dataIndex: 'title',
    title: 'Name',
    width: '45%'
  },
  {
    dataIndex: 'tag',
    title: 'Tag',
    render: tag => <Tag>{tag}</Tag>,
    width: '10%'
  },
  {
    dataIndex: 'description',
    title: 'Description',
    width: '40%'
  }
];
```

Refer to `Table` [Column API](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column).

Fork of your codebox:

[image: Edit Q-56732104-Constrain Columns Width]

Comment: Not related to this question but I had a question regarding the antd's transfer component. It will be great to also have your help on a separate question I asked here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748215/how-to-also-transfer-the-children-across-the-component

Comment: I'll check this out